# JobTypeLogic and JobType classes in MVC business logic

Tags: c#, mvc

I am working on an MVC solution.  My DAL layer I could solve with Repository classes, everything is working great.

But in my BLL layer I have repetitive code:

My CRUD is the same, my fields and consructor are different.
I can also have some extra methods.

Is there a way to solve this properly?

#### Class 1

```
public class JobTypeLogic
{
    #region Fields
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }
    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    public Repository<JobType> JobTypeEngine { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public JobTypeLogic()
    {
        JobType = new JobType();
        JobTypeEngine = unitOfWork.Repository<JobType>();
    }
    #endregion

    #region CRUD

    public void Add()
    {
        JobTypeEngine.Add(JobType);
    }

    public JobType Get(long id)
    {
        return JobType = JobTypeEngine.Get(id);
    }

    public void Edit()
    {
        JobTypeEngine.Edit(JobType);
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        JobTypeEngine.Delete(JobType); 
    }

    public List<JobType> List()
    {
        return JobTypeEngine.List.ToList();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

#### Class 2

```
public class JobLogic
{
    #region Fields
    public Job Job { get; set; }        
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobTypeList { get; set; }
    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    public Repository<Job> JobEngine;
    private Repository<JobType> JobTypeEngine;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public JobLogic()
    {
        Job = new Job();
        JobEngine = unitOfWork.Repository<Job>();
        JobTypeEngine = unitOfWork.Repository<JobType>();
        JobTypeList = GetJobTypeList();
    }
    #endregion

    #region CRUD

    public void Add()
    {
        JobEngine.Add(Job);
    }

    public Job Get(long id)
    {
        return Job = JobEngine.Get(id);
    }

    public void Edit()
    {
        JobEngine.Edit(Job);
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        JobEngine.Delete(Job);
    }

    public List<Job> List()
    {
        return JobEngine.List.ToList();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methode

    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetJobTypeList()
    {
        JobTypeEngine = unitOfWork.Repository<JobType>();   
        var jobs = JobTypeEngine.List
                    .Select(x =>
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                                Text = x.Name
                            });

        return new SelectList(jobs, "Value", "Text");
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 2):

This feels bad to me:

```
private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();

public JobTypeLogic()
{
    JobTypeEngine = unitOfWork.Repository<JobType>();
}
```

This begs for IoC/DI, otherwise I cannot see how you'd test your code.

---

`JobTypeEngine.List.ToList();`: I don't know what's worse, that you've got a property named `List`, or that it apparently isn't a `List` at all.

---

`public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobTypeList { get; set; }`: Does a `SelectListItem` belong in the BLL? Why isn't that a `JobType` instead, and why aren't you calling it `JobTypes` (especially since it is an `IEnumerable` and not a `List`)?

---

`GetJobTypeList()` doesn't seem to be used. It also again assigns `JobTypeEngine` even though this already happened in the `JobLogic` constructor.

Comment: Thanks for you comments I will look into it. In meanwhile I used a generic class for my repetitive code. I need to test it, and then I can share my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generic abstract base class to inherit from. I wouldn't, but I'll get to that later. First, let's look at the base class.

```
abstract class BusinessBase<TRepository<TBusinessType>> where TRepository : IRepository<TBusinessType>
{
    // repository property & crud operations on the IRepository here
}
```

But we have to ask ourselves if this is real duplication, or apparent duplication. The fact is, the business logic is extremely likely to be different for these two objects. They might be identical now, but in 6 months time, they won't be. The logic is going to drift apart and you'll be left wishing they didn't inherit from the same base class.

The code is fine. Ship it.

Comment: Thanks for you comments I will look into it. In meanwhile I used a generic class for my repetitive code. I need to test it, and then I can share my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response.
I solved the problem by creating a generic base class and inherited from that class.

Base class

```
 public class GenericLogic<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private Repository<T> engine;
    private UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
    public T Entity;

    public GenericLogic()
    {
        this.engine = unitOfWork.Repository<T>();
    }        
    #region CRUD

    public void Add()
    {
        engine.Add(Entity);
    }
    public T Get(long id)
    {}
    public void Edit()
    {}
   public void Delete()
    {}
    public List<T> List()
    {}
    #endregion
}
```

The two BLL classes (and the rest of the BLL) become lighter and not repetitive.

BLL class

```
public class JobLogic : GenericLogic<Job>
{
    #region Fields
    public Job Job { get; set; }    
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> JobTypeList { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public JobLogic()
    {
        Job = new Job();
        JobTypeList = GetJobTypeList();
    }
    #endregion

    #region Methode
    private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetJobTypeList()
    {
        UnitOfWork unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
        Repository<JobType> jobTypeEngine = unitOfWork.Repository<JobType>();   
        var jobs = jobTypeEngine.List
                    .Select(x =>
                            new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = x.ID.ToString(),
                                Text = x.Name
                            });
        return new SelectList(jobs, "Value", "Text");
    }
    #endregion
}
```

DAL classes is

```
public class Repository<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    private readonly FlowContext context;
    private IDbSet<T> entities;
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    public Repository(FlowContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public T Get(object id)
    {}

    public void Add(T entity)
    {}

    public void Edit(T entity)
    {}

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {}

    private IDbSet<T> Entities
    {}
}
```

The only problem I have with this solution is that I can't use the Entity field from my base class in MVC. Therefore I created a Field Job. This has todo with the binding between the controller and the HTML page.

Hopefully is this code a great help for other people.